# clip-path (using url) not working on firefox

Tags: css, clip-path

EDIT The following problem was fixed in FF by now /EDIT

at several places it says, Firefox supports clip-path if used with the url(..) version.
However I could not make the most simple example work, even though it works on Chromium (53). I tested Firefox 49 and Firefox 38.

```css
#Top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100px; width: 100px;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#Schnitt);
  -moz-clip-path: url(#Schnitt); /*tested with and without that line*/
  clip-path: url(#Schnitt);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Testseite</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="Top" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="Schnitt">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="29" />
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Funnily, if I run this code in the preview for this post, also Firefox clips properly, but it does not if I open my local files. (Which neither include more nor less code.)
Any ideas?
Thank you that far.